# MongoDB weird writeResult behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am using mongodb (v2.6.7) and mongo (2.6.7) shell client.

I am trying to use the WriteResult object returned by the insert and and update commands.

According to [mongodocs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/) in case of error it returns a writeResult object with writeError subdocument. But I am not able to access this subdocument in shell or in mongo's javascript file.

Below is an illustration of my problem.

- I insert an object and get the successful writeResult.
- Then I am inserting again with the same _id and I am getting the writeResult correctly printed on the screen which has "writeError" correctly set.
- Also the writeResult object seems to contain the writeError when I print it with printjson() method
- But when I print it with JSON.stringify() then I am not able to see the "writeError".
- Also writeResult.writeError is coming as undefined so I am not able to access its writeResult.writeError.code property.

Can someone please explain why is this happening and what is the correct way.

```
afv:PRIMARY>writeResult=db.sysinfo.insert({_id:"myid",otherData:"otherDataValue"})

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

afv:PRIMARY>writeResult=db.sysinfo.insert({_id:"myid",otherData:"otherDataValue"})

WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: afvadmin.sysinfo.$_id_  dup key: { : \"myid\" }"
    }
})

afv:PRIMARY> printjson(writeResult)
{
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: afvadmin.sysinfo.$_id_  dup key: { : \"myid\" }"
    }
}

afv:PRIMARY> JSON.stringify(writeResult);
{"nInserted":0,"nUpserted":0,"nMatched":0,"nModified":0,"nRemoved":0}

afv:PRIMARY> writeResult.writeError

afv:PRIMARY> writeResult.nInserted
0

afv:PRIMARY> writeResult.writeError.code
2015-02-02T16:34:42.402+0530 TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

afv:PRIMARY> writeResult["writeError"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why it was implemented this way, but to access the contained `writeError` subdocument, you call `getWriteError()` on a `WriteResult` object:

```javascript
> writeResult.getWriteError()
WriteError({
  "index": 0,
  "code": 11000,
  "errmsg": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$_id_  dup key: { : \"myid\" }",
  "op": {
    "_id": "myid",
    "otherData": "otherDataValue"
  }
})

> writeResult.getWriteError().code
11000
```

I couldn't find any documentation for this. I figured it out by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice after typing `writeResult.` in the shell to see what's available.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the methods to get the WriteError object as mentioned already, you can also get the raw response and work on that:

```javascript
> writeResult.getRawResponse()
{
    "writeErrors" : [
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "code" : 11000,
            "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.bar.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400') }",
            "op" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400"),
                "a" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
}
```

So, you can then do something like this and things are a bit more consistent:

```javascript
> raw = writeResult.getRawResponse();
> raw.writeErrors[0].errmsg
insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.bar.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400') }
> printjson(raw.writeErrors[0])
{
    "index" : 0,
    "code" : 11000,
    "errmsg" : "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.bar.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400') }",
    "op" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400"),
        "a" : 1
    }
}    
> JSON.stringify(raw.writeErrors[0])
    {"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: foo.bar.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('54cf8152733aa5e886f0e400') }"}
```